# Dealing with conditional OR statements (simple Markov Chain question)

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I have a Markov chain with three states, X, Y and Z, and the following transition matrix;

$$ P =\pmatrix{0.5 & 0.5 & 0 \\ 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.2 \\ 0 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\}$$

Now, what I need is to compute the probability of being in states Y or Z next "turn" given we're currently either in state  Y or Z.

So, if we were in state Y, the probability of being in state Y or Z next turn would be 0.6.
If we were in state Z, the probability of being in state Y or Z next turn would be 1.

The problem I'm having is what to do with both these probabilities to get my final answer.

Comment: The answer depends on what specifically is meant by "given we're currently in either state Y or Z". As you point out, the answer depends on the probability we're currently in Y versus the probability we're currently in Z. The exercise very likely expects you to compute the steady state probabilities for all states (a simple computation reveals that $p(X) = p(Y) = p(Z) = \frac{1}{3}$ is the unique steady state), and the conditional probability of being in either state is equal. A quick computation then reveals that the final probability is $0.8$.

Comment: @COTO Actually the steady state is proportional to 4:5:2, not 1:1:1.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking I would need to compute the stationary distribution but wanted a hint in that direction.